# Using grep in a for loop

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a for loop with grep.  When grep returns a value I want to display the message "running".  If no value is returned then display "available".

I think there is something is wrong with my if statement, but I can't find anything.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
    #!/bin/sh
    #JWR1.0, REL1.10

    echo "Content-type: text/html"
    echo ""

    chk_port = 'ps -ef | grep "port $i -"'

    for (( i=1; i<=5; i++ ))
    do
            if [[ $chk_port ]]; then
                    echo "Running - $i<br>"
            else
                    echo "Available - $i<br>"
            fi
    done

    echo "<br>"

    # For debugging


    ps -ef | grep "port 1 -"
```

Sample output:

```
    Available - 1
    Available - 2
    Available - 3
    Available - 4
    Available - 5

    apache 7706 7700 0 15:07 ? 00:00:00 grep port 1 -
```

Comment: Try replacing $chk_port with this: $(ps -ef | grep "port $i -")

Comment: @ed.: That makes the `for`-loop rather pointless, since it just checks five times to see if the process was originally running . . .

Comment: @ruakh: No - it evaluates $i each time in the loop now.

Comment: @ed.: Oh, I see; you're not suggesting to set `chk_port` to `$(ps -ef | grep "port $i -")`, you're suggesting to dispense with `$chk_port` and instead use `$(ps -ef | grep "port $i -")`. O.K., yes, good. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I guess your problem is, there is **no** `port $i` in your ps's output, but your script thinks it exists.

The problem is, the command `grep port $i -` is also in `ps -ef`'s output, it was clear in your debugging output. You can test it with `ps -ef|grep foo`

To avoid it, there is a trick, just do

```
chk_port=$(ps -ef | grep "[p]ort $i -")
```

for example:

```
kent$  ps -ef|grep nothing  
kent     10226  4752  0 00:36 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=auto nothing

kent$  ps -ef|grep [n]othing
zsh: no matches found: [n]othing
```

Also you could check the return code of grep (grep -q) to decide if the pattern was found. If no matches found, grep returns 1, otherwise 0.